# find least common multiple of numbers 1-20

Tags: python

I am having some trouble with this algorithm.  I am attempting to find the least common multiple for a given range of numbers.  The following functions find the factors of a number, count the different factors in the number, counts the factors so that I can find the lcm of the range of numbers based on [this](http://www.math.com/school/subject1/lessons/S1U3L3DP.html) algorithm, and then finally calculates the lcm; however, if you run this code, the print statement at the bottom does not print the correct answer.  Instead I get a number that I KNOW for sure is not right.  I mainly need a second set of eyes to point out the problem with this code.  Can anyone help?

```
from collections import defaultdict

def factors_of(number):
    factors = [];
    i = 2
    while number >= 2:
        if number % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
            number = number / i
        else:
            i += 1
    return factors

def count_factors(number):
    count = {}
    factors = factors_of(number)
    for factor in factors:
        if not factor in count:
            count[factor] = 1
        else:
            count[factor] += 1
    return count

def count_factors_of_numbers_in_range(start, stop):
    count = defaultdict(int)
    for number in range(start, stop):
        factor_count = count_factors(number)
        for key in factor_count:
            if count[key] < factor_count[key]:
                count[key] = factor_count[key]
    return dict(count)

def find_lcm_of_numbers_in_range(start, stop):
    count = count_factors_of_numbers_in_range(start, stop)
    lcm = 1
    for key in count:
        total = count[key] * key
        lcm = total * lcm
    return lcm

print find_lcm_of_numbers_in_range(1, 21)
```

Comment: Well, I think for starters your you first function does not produce the right result I don't think. Try it with 12, and you get a list of [2, 2, 3], when the correct list should be [2, 3, 4, 6], or am i missing something?

Comment: I am finding all of the prime factors. If you read the link in my question, you should be able to understand how this algorithm should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I did wrong.  I guess I just needed a good night's sleep.

The problem did not lie in a quirk with Python (which was what I thought this might be) but in my own implementation of the algorithm.  In my code

```
def find_lcm_of_numbers_in_range(start, stop):
    count = count_factors_of_numbers_in_range(start, stop)
    lcm = 1
    for key in count:
        total = count[key] * key
        lcm = total * lcm
    return lcm
```

I messed up multiplying all of the numbers together in the statement `total`.  Instead of multiplying the number 2 by the number 4, I needed to multiply 2 by itself 4 times (`2 ** 4`).  By simply tweaking the code to look like

```
def find_lcm_of_numbers_in_range(start, stop):
    count = count_factors_of_numbers_in_range(start, stop)
    lcm = 1
    for key in count:
        total = key ** count[key]
        lcm = total * lcm
    return lcm
```

everything worked out and I am now happy.  :)

Answer (score 0):

why can't you simply find gcd by euclid's algorithm and the multiply the numbers and divide by gcd to find LCM?

```
def decorator(d):
    """This is a decorator that will decorate all decorators. This will add update_wrapper
    to all decorators.
    (fun) -> fun
    """
    def _d(f):
        return update_wrapper(d(f), f)
    return update_wrapper(_d, d)



@decorator
def nary(f):
    """This is docp implementation of n_ary function above.
    (function) -> function
   Tue-23-April-2013
    """
    def n_ary(x, *args):
        if len(args) == 0:
            return x
        return f(x, n_ary(*args))
    return n_ary

@nary
def gcd(a, b):
    """Calculate the Greatest Common Divisor of a and b.

    Unless b==0, the result will have the same sign as b (so that when
    b is divided by it, the result comes out positive).
    """
    while b:
        a, b = b, a%b
    return a
```

Comment: This sounds logical, would you mind elaborating? (How do you apply GCD and then LCM to 20 numbers instead of 2 for example). Some Python code or at least pseudo code would be nice.

Comment: In the answer, not as a comment, elaborations would be welcome too.. Thanks.

Comment: Edited to include example code. nary converts function that takes two args into function that takes any number of args.

Comment: I suppose this would work.  I had never really had any personal experience with finding the least common multiple this way.