# Python: divide elements of a list based on a condition

Tags: python, algorithm, control-flow

I am trying to find the LCM of first 20 natural numbers (Project Euler question 5). For that, my algorithm is:

1. have numbers 1 to 20 in a list
2. Divide only those elements of the list that are divisible by i where i is in the range (2-20).
3. Whatever numbers are left in the list, multiply them and that will be the lcm.

This is the naivest algorithm which we actually used to calculate lcm in school for the first time.

Now, I donot know how to divide the elements of the list based on the condition.
I have tried:

```
a=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
for x in a:
    if(x%2==0):
        x=x/2
```

This does not seem to work.
I also tried:

```
a=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
a1=[if(x%2==0): x/2 for x in a]
```

the above with both with and without ":" after the if condition. This does not work. I have the following questions:

a. Why isn't the first loop working correctly?

b. Can someone tell me how I can do this?

c. Will my algorithm work correctly?

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: @kasra- his is just a part of the entire program. I intend to get the lcm of the 20 numbers by prime factorization.

Comment: You don't need prime factorisation per se, but you have to take care of counting factors just the number of times they need to be taken into account (see the answers below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) the variable `x` takes the value of the list `a` , but not modified, it is not a reference of list, the following code does what you want:

```
a=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
for i in range(len(a)):
  if(a[i]%2==0):
    a[i]=a[i]/2
```

b) y C)

```
a=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

def f(x):
  if(x%2==0): 
    return x/2
  return x

a1=[f(x) for x in a]
```

> Whatever numbers are left in the list, multiply them and that will be the lcm.

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, a1)
```

Comment: I'm not sure the code above provides the right answer. For instance, in the case of a = [2,4,8,16], the lcm is 16, but the answer from the code above is 64. Again, for the given example, the result is 2375880867360000, but the correct answer is 232792560, which you can check also in Wolfram Alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=least%20common%20multiple%20of%202%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C11%2C12%2C13%2C14%2C15%2C16%2C17%2C18%2C19%2C20

Comment: @juandesant 2375880867360000 is only the result of multiplying each element of a1 ..... has no relation to lcm

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. that is what I understood from your answer on how to calculate the lcm: that after filtering by 2 in all numbers in a, the reduce step gives you the lcm. What I'm saying is that that is not correct.

Comment: @juandesant you 're right .... I just responded to "multiply them" and I hoped that OP will solve the lcm problem by their own efforts

Answer (score 1):

> a. Why isn't the first loop working correctly?

For the same reason as:

[Foreach in Python not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828210/foreach-in-python-not-working-as-expected/29828271#29828271)

> b. Can someone tell me how I can do this?

You can do either:

```
a=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    if x%2==0:
        a[i]=x/2
```

Or:

```
a=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
a1=[x/2 if x%2==0 else x for x in a]
```

> c. Will my algorithm work correctly?

I don't think so. You'll end up dividing everyone by itself and the result will always be 1.

But there are other questions here in SO that have simple answers, like:

[find least common multiple of numbers 1-20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715545/find-least-common-multiple-of-numbers-1-20)

Answer (score 1):

**a) Why is this loop not working correctly?**

As @jose-ricardo-bustos-m indicates, the `x` is not a reference, is a local copy to each element of the array `a`, and cannot modify the array in the for loop. You can use, instead:

```
a=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
for i,x in enumerate(a): #used to provide a value, and an index
    if(x%2==0):
        a[i]=x/2
```

**b) Can someone tell me how I can do this?**

You can try to use the ternary if operator and list comprehension:

```
a = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
b = [x/2 if x%2==0 else x  for x in a]
```

**c) Will my algorithm work correctly**

You have to keep track of the numbers you have already used, and you might need to divide by the same number more than once. But if you do that, and keep dividing by the same number _until the resulting list is equal to the previous one, and then move to the next, you can later multiply all numbers used, times the remainder of the list (but if you go to the max number in the list, the remaining list will contain just 1's).

```
def f(l,n): # divides items in a which are divisible by n, or leaves them
    return [x/n if x%n==0 else x  for x in l]

lcm = 1
a=[2,3,4,5,6,7]

# we go from the smallest to the largest number in your list
for i in range(2,max(a)+1):
    repeat_next_time = True
    while repeat_next_time:
        b = f(a,i)
        if a != b:
            print('Using %s as a factor' % i)
            a = b
            lcm *= i
            # print(a) # to get the status of the a list
        else:
            repeat_next_time = False
# finally, for numbers which might have not been divided yet,
# multiply the lcm by all of the remaining items
lcm *= reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, a)
```

It works even if there are common divisors, or repeated numbers in the list. Try, for instance, with `a = [2,2,2]`, or `a = [2,3,6]`, or `a = [8,7,4,7]`.

Comment: If you apply this code using `a = range(2,20+1)`, you get the actual answer to your problem: `lcm = 232792560`. You can check it with Wolfram Alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=least%20common%20multiple%20of%202%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C11%2C12%2C13%2C14%2C15%2C16%2C17%2C18%2C19%2C20